# Spring Boot WAR vs JAR File Path Differences

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, gradle

I created an application that uses Groovy, WAR, and Gradle for the settings, other than the JPA, MVC, etc... that I chose for the project. I've been working on it and running it as a Spring Boot project whenever I start it from STS to test and work on.

I decided I was at a good point to generate a WAR and drop it in a brand instance of Tomcat, for the sake of experiencing launching an application.

The errors that I'm running into are all related to file paths, mainly `FileNotFoundException`. I have a directory under `src/main/resources/static` that I placed all my static content, css, etc... When I run the WAR in Tomcat externally, it's looking for static content in the Tomcat `/bin/` directory. If I copy the files over to that directory and restart Tomcat, it works fine.

The biggest hurdle that I'm trying to cross is knowing how exactly are the file paths transferred to a WAR and where exactly I should be placing the files. I thought I was on the right path but maybe I misunderstood how that works.

**EDIT**

Just for testing, I ran the WAR file as an executable and it works out of the box. I only have issues when I take it to an existing Tomcat instance. It's more or less for knowing how it works and getting it to work right by having the proper setup, that's what I'm after.

**EDIT**

I realized why it was the `/bin` directory; it had to do with where I was launching it from. I was running `./catalina run` from that directory and that happened to be the directory it wanted the static resources in at that moment.

Comment: My assumption is that you put your war in the webapps folder and start the tomcat. That way your app is deployed to`http://localhost:<port>/<name of the war>`. Try to rename the war to ROOT.war, restart the tomcat and try to access the app on `http://localhost:<port>`

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I renamed the WAR to ROOT and dropped it in the `webapps` folder

Comment: That's strange, Spring Boot exposes the static contect from classpath:static folder, so for example if you have `myfile.html` in src/main/resources/static, you should be able to access id with `http://localhost:<port>/myfile.html`. Do you have any custom configuration  for static resources?

Comment: I tried both with and without a resource handler which I had pointed to the following: `registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");' but it's useless and doesn't have an impact one way or another. I believe that if you have resources outside the `/resources, /static /public or /META-INF/resources`, you don't need a resource handler. I'm pretty confused on the whole setup, there isn't really a clear understanding of what is the "best practices" way to do it.

Comment: In a WAR deployment, where should the static content be? I'm not sure why, but it's expecting it in the `/bin` directory, is that right?

Comment: With Spring Boot application the best practice is to keep the static resources in /resources, /static /public or /META-INF/resources as written in the docs. It doesn't matter if you user jar with embedded tomcat or a war file. I think that there is a problem with your project. Can you try to create new Spring starter project  from the STS and just put something in the resources folder. it should work for both jar and war deployment.

Comment: I did like you said and the new project worked fine. I'm not sure at this point what I need to look at and fix in order to get this to work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Obviously there is something thet overrides the spring boot default config. Take a look at this - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration Check if you have @EnableWebMvc. If you do, the default config is overriden.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to thank Evgeni for the comments and helping me in the right direction. I took his suggestions regarding creating a new project to identify what possibly went wrong. After doing so, i was able to eliminate the gradle errors that I was facing and everything was moving in the right direction.

The answer to the question that I asked: Difference between war vs jar file paths...

There is no difference whatsoever, if you have your project configured right. I was running into issues with the paths because they were hard-coded like so: src/main/resources... in the controllers and other classes that I was trying to access resources from. Once I was able to solve that issue by replacing the hard-coded paths to resources, I no longer had issues with paths and was able to run the war in an external Tomcat and also as a standalone executable.